# How to create a custom JSON layout from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL query in PHP that pulls back two columns of results

Column One is Label
Column Two is Value

I have read http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP but im struggling to understand how I can do the following JSON in PHP from MySQL

```
[
  {
    key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: [
      { 
        "label": "One",
        "value" : 29.765957771107
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Two",
        "value" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Three",
        "value" : 32.807804682612
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Four",
        "value" : 196.45946739256
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Five",
        "value" : 0.19434030906893
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Six",
        "value" : 98.079782601442
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Seven",
        "value" : 13.925743130903
      } , 
      { 
        "label": "Eight",
        "value" : 5.1387322875705
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can manually write a loop to output the raw text to form a JSON like above but I really want to use **json_encode**

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost'; //MySQL database
$username = 'root'; //MySQL user
$password = ''; //MySQL Password

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=etl", $username, $password);

    $query = "select label, value from table";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!empty($result)) {
        echo '[
        {
          key: "Cumulative Return",
          values: [';

        for ($row = 0; $row < count($result); $row++) {
            echo "{";
            echo '"label": "' . $result[$row]['Label'] . '",';
            echo '"Value": ' . $result[$row]['Value'];
            echo "},";
            echo '       ]
      }
    ]';
        }

    }
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Can this be done? if so how?

Comment: You can use `json_encode`. You just have to format an array similar to how you need the JSON you mentioned. I would write the code, but I'm on my way out so will do later :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$hostname = 'localhost'; //MySQL database
$username = 'root'; //MySQL user
$password = ''; //MySQL Password

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=etl", $username, $password);

    $query = "select label, value from table";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $values = array();

    for($row = 0; $row < count($result); $row++)
    {
        $values[] = array('label' => $result[$row]['Label'], 'value' => $result[$row]['Value']);
    }

    $to_encode = array(
                        array('key' => 'Cumulative Return', 
                              'values' => $values;
                              )
                        );
    echo json_encode($to_encode);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `json_encode()`

```
$jsonArr = array( 'key' => 'Cumulative Return' , 'values' => array() );


foreach ($result as $res) 
{
   $jsonArr['values'][] = array('label'=>$res['Label'],'value'=>$res['value']);

}

echo json_encode($jsonArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create the array in the way you want it to be converted to json:

```
$encode = array(
    'key' => 'Cumulative Return', 
    'values' => $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
);
echo json_encode($encode);
```

This should be what you are asking for.

Comment: This should do it. The only thing that might be an issue is that the "label" and "value" will be capitalized, since that's how they're defined in the db (judging by the "$result[$row]['Label']" in the for loop). But that can be solved with aliases in the query itself

Comment: In that case: `SELECT Label AS label, Value AS value FROM`

Answer (score 1):

That's the usefulness of JSON - that you don't need to bother to encode it manually.

```
$json = array();
$results = array();
$json['key'] = 'Cumulative return';

foreach ($row as $entry) {
    $results['label'] = $entry['Label'];
    $results['value'] = $entry['Value'];
    $json['value'][] = $results;
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

And that's it. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Iam using code igniter

this is how i created custom json from the values from the data base hope it helps

```html
function getData() {

  $query = $this -> db -> get('gcm_users');
  
  $result_array=array();

  if ($query -> num_rows() > 0) {
   
   $results=$query->result();

   foreach ( $results as $row) {
    
    $data=array();
    
    $data['name']=$row->name;
    $data['email']=$row->email;
    
    array_push($result_array,$data) ;  
   }

   

   return json_encode($result_array);

  } else {

   echo "something went wrong";

  }
 }
```

this my function for retriving data from db since im using a frame work such as Code igniter i dont have to worry about my other sql operation hope you can extract what you need from this code..

output is like this

```html
[{"name":"allu","email":"allu@gmail.com"},{"name":"ameeen","email":"cdfdfd@gmail.com"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I build a simple function (I prefer to use it then json_encode - because I have full control of the fetched data):

```
    public function mysqlToJoson($mysqlarray)
    {
        $json_string = "[";

        while ($array = $mysqlarray->fetch()) {
            $i = 1;
            if ($json_string != "["){$json_string .= ",";}
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if ($i == 1) {
                    $json_string .= '{"' . $key . '":' . '"' . htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '"';
                } else $json_string .= ',"' . $key . '":' . '"' . htmlentities($value,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '"';
                $i++;
            }
            $json_string .= '}';
        }
        $json_string .= ']';
        return $json_string;
    }
```